# Refresh data only on the filtered condition

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 button group, refresh button and table.
ALL | Dover | Orlando

On page load, All the data is displayed in table by calling api.

Using angularjs filter i have filtered data based on city i.e Dover or Orlando.

Current scenario:
When user is on Dover and clicks refresh button all the data is loaded again i.e ALL and Refresh are have same api call.

Required scenario:
When user is on Dover and clicks refresh button only Dover data should get refresh.

code:

```
            <div class="myrow">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <label for="documentStatus">Queues: </label>                      
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" ng-click="updateData(); myFilter = null">ALL</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myFilter = {city : 'Dover'}">Dover</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myFilter = {city : 'Orlando'}">Orlando</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container" ng-init="updateData()">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Refresh" ng-click="myFilter = null; updateData()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh
                    </button>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Queue</th>
                            <th>No of Documents</th>
                            <th>Oldest document Datetime</th>
                            <th>Allocated Users</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="queue in Queues | filter: myFilter">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label class="checkbox-table">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="queue.isChecked" id="check-box-{{$index}}">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{{ queue.queue }}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-2">{{ queue.noOfDocuments }}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-2">{{ queue.oldestDoc}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-5">{{ queue.allocatedUsers}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: This sounds more like a backend issue to me, if you only want to fetch resources filtered by the city `orlando`. 

If you're using angulars `$http` you can throw in the `parameters` property which will translate to `GET` parameters in the ajax call.

Comment: Added code for the above..

Comment: Where is your `update function`?

Comment: update is fetching json data from web api.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use angular.copy(arr):

```
 var data = {
         original: myOriginalData,
         filteredData: angular.copy(myOriginalData) //this is unbind link on the arrayy
    };
```